# An array in java printing and returning

Tags: java, arrays

I am new to java and am doing some exercises to learn. I have been working on arrays, and have been able to print out my first array. But the second one does not print anything, just wondering where I went wrong, thank you very much.

```
package Justice;

import java.util.Arrays;

class ArrayDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] anArray;

    anArray = new int[10];

    anArray[0] = 100;
    anArray[1] = 200;
    anArray[2] = 300;
    anArray[3] = 400;
    anArray[4] = 500;
    anArray[5] = 600;
    anArray[6] = 700;
    anArray[7] = 800;
    anArray[8] = 900;
    anArray[9] = 1000;
    System.out.println (Arrays.toString(anArray));

}  


public static String[] hello(String[] args) {
    String[] myArray;


    myArray = new String[5];
    myArray[0] = "hello";
    myArray[2] = "world";

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray));
    return (myArray);

}
```

Comment: how should it print if you never call `hello` ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

is called if you run your Java class from shell.

If you want to call

```
hello(String[] args)
```

you must call it explicitely in your main-method. You can add the following line below your first print statement:

```
hello(null);
```

Comment: The best answer because it explains WHY the solution works instead of simply correcting the code.

Comment: yes, thank you, just wondering what the null is for and what else I can put in the brackets

Comment: You can either put an object of type `String[]` or `null` in the brackets. `null` means you don't pass any object to the method. In your case it doesn't matter, because you don't use the given parameter. Therefore you could define your method like `public static String[] hello()` then you must not pass anything to the method. The "args" in `public static void main(String[] args)` contains the parameters that you used when starting the jvm.

Answer (score 0):

Please try `deepToString(Object[])` method instead of `toString(args)`.

you can try method `deepToString(Object[])` to show all content of that Array.

```
String [] arr = new String[3];
arr[0]="asdf";
arr[1]="asdf";
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr));
```

it will print output like as

```
[asdf, asdf, null]
```

Another way to do this is...
you can also iterate this array over taking length as a criteria in a forloop.

```
for(int i=0 i<anArray.length;i++)
System.out.println(anArray[i]);
```

Thank YOu

Answer (score 0):

Paste this `System.out.println(hello(args));` after System.out.println (Arrays.toString(anArray));

will give you Output: `[hello, null, world, null, null]`

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your code

```
package Justice;

import java.util.Arrays;

class ArrayDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] anArray;

    anArray = new int[10];

    anArray[0] = 100;
    anArray[1] = 200;
    anArray[2] = 300;
    anArray[3] = 400;
    anArray[4] = 500;
    anArray[5] = 600;
    anArray[6] = 700;
    anArray[7] = 800;
    anArray[8] = 900;
    anArray[9] = 1000;
    System.out.println (Arrays.toString(anArray));

    // This is the method call
    hello(null);             // You don't need the 'String[] args' in your method because you've not used the arguments


}  


public static String[] hello(String[] args) {
    String[] myArray;


    myArray = new String[5];
    myArray[0] = "hello";
    myArray[2] = "world";

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray));
    return (myArray);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your `main()` to this:

```
class ArrayDemo { 
public static void main(String[] args) {

int[] anArray;

anArray = new int[10];

anArray[0] = 100;
anArray[1] = 200;
anArray[2] = 300;
anArray[3] = 400;
anArray[4] = 500;
anArray[5] = 600;
anArray[6] = 700;
anArray[7] = 800;
anArray[8] = 900;
anArray[9] = 1000;
System.out.println (Arrays.toString(anArray));

ArrayDemo obj = new ArrayDemo();
obj.hello();
}
```

And make the `hello()` method like this:

```
public void hello() {
String[] myArray;


myArray = new String[5];
myArray[0] = "hello";
myArray[2] = "world";

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray));
}
```

Comment: This works great, thank you. Just wondering what the null is for, and what else I can put in the brackets, thanks again

Comment: @samujoe - I didn't quite understand what null are you talking about and also which brackets are you talking about? My bad! So can you please elaborate your query a bit ?

Comment: In this method call ,,,,  hello(null);

Comment: I was wondering what the null is for and what else I can put between the brackets

Comment: And I would like to also say thank you very much to everyone, this has been very helpful to a beginner looking to learn :)

Answer (score 0):

public static String[] hello(String[] args) is not called. it should be called from public static void main().